# Roots of a quintic function

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I need some pointers in the right direction for this question:

Three of the roots of the equation

$ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f=0$

are $-2$, $2i$ and $1+i$. Find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ and $f$.

I know that if $-2$, $2i$, and $1+i$ are the roots of the equation, then the factors of the equation must be $(x+2)$, $(x-2i)$ and $(x-(1+i))$.

I am assuming that another root of the equation must be $1-i$ (therefore another factor must be $(x-(1-i))$), to make a complex conjugate pair.

I have tried to expand out

$(x+2)(x-2i)(x-(1+i))(x-(1-i))$ = $x^4-2x^3i+4ix^2+8ix+2x^2-8i$

but I am unsure of what to do next (and I'm unsure if that's the correct expansion!). Can I set this equal to my quintic polynomial above? Is there a quicker way to work this out?

Comment: How about the fifth root? You forgot that in the expansion.

Comment: Is the fifth root the complex conjugate of 2i? (i.e. -2i)?

Comment: Yes, that is it. See my answer.

Comment: Are the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f\;$ real?

Comment: @gammatester: Don't they have to be real since this is a fifth degree equation and we know there are 4 complex roots (2 conjugates of the two stated) and a real one?

Comment: @gammatester It doesn't specify.

Comment: @Jack: It _has_ to specify! Otherwise the question is impossible.

Comment: @Sheheryar Zaidi: This is about complex numbers, why should they be real? If there are no restrictions, you can add just two other real or complex numbers as roots.

Comment: @TonyK That is the question straight from the textbook. It does not say if the coefficients are real.

Comment: @gammatester: Of course, I see what you mean. Then, shouldn't we assume that they are real, because as TonyK said, it's impossible to solve otherwise.

Comment: @JackGriffiths: What is the source? Which book are you using?

Comment: [http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0435519239/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=479289247&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0199117837&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=00C358VHRCNN3WVEJ1BT](It is this book) (you can click on the cover and search for 'Three of the roots of'. Question 11, Page 29.

Comment: I checked this link: [book chapter pdf](http://www.pearsonschoolsandfecolleges.co.uk/FEAndVocational/Mathematics/ALevel/EdexcelModularMathematicsforASandALevel/Resources/FurtherPureMathematics1/FP1_Chapter_1.pdf) and clearly, they are dealing only with real roots.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi: I think you mean "Clearly, they are dealing only with real coefficients." The roots can be complex.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, wasn't able to edit the comment for some reason!

Comment: In my opinion, that is not a super-well written book. On p. 24, it does state for skill 1.8: "You can solve some types of polynomial equations with real coefficients", and then I guess you're supposed to take that for granted throughout the rest of the section and exercises without further comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: expand this $$(x+2)(x-2i)(x+2i)(x-(1+i))(x-(1-i))$$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Expanding this will give the values of a=1, b=0, c=2, d=4, e=-8 and f=16 (assuming a,b,c,d,e and f are real).

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the three roots in the polynomial expression, you get the system

$$\begin{align}2\to&&-32a+16b-8c+4d-2e+f&=0\\
2i\to&&32ia+16b-8ic-4d+f+2ei&=0\\
1+i\to&&(-4-4i)a-4b+(-2+2i)c+2id+f+e(1+i)&=0\end{align}\\
$$ or, separating the real and imaginary parts,

$$\begin{align}-32a+16b-8c+4d-2e+f=0\\
16b-4d+f=0\\
32a-8c+2e=0\\
-4a-4b-2c+e+f=0\\
-4a+2c+2d+e=0\end{align}\\
$$

A solution of this linear system is

$$b=0, c=2a, d=4a, e=-8a, f=16a.$$

Comment: This solution is much less efficient than direct multiplication.